# Why My MVVM does not work when I change data on the fly?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm

My xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMetroChartsVB"        
        xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:GravityApps.Mandelkow.MetroCharts;assembly=GravityApps.Mandelkow.MetroCharts"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TestPageViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <chart:ClusteredBarChart ChartTitle="Example1 " ChartSubTitle="Test1">
                <chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series>
                    <chart:ChartSeries SeriesTitle="Errors" ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"
                                       DisplayMember="Category" ValueMember="Number"/>
                </chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series>                    
            </chart:ClusteredBarChart>
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Height="31" Margin="0,0,405,0" Content="Change Data"/>
        </StackPanel>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My view:

```vb
Imports GravityApps.Mandelkow.MetroCharts Class MainWindow

Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim test As New TestPageViewModel
    test.changeData()
End Sub End Class
```

My viewModel:

```vb
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class TestPageViewModel

    Public Property Errors() As ObservableCollection(Of TestClass)
        Get
            Return m_Errors
        End Get
        Private Set
            m_Errors = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Errors As ObservableCollection(Of TestClass)
    Public Sub New()
        Errors = New ObservableCollection(Of TestClass)
        Errors.Add(New TestClass("Data1", 5))
        Errors.Add(New TestClass("Data2", 10))
        Errors.Add(New TestClass("Data5", 15))
    End Sub

    Public Sub changeData()
        Errors.Clear()
        Errors.Add(New TestClass("DAta9", 10))
    End Sub

End Class
```

My Model:

```vb
Public Class TestClass
    Public Property Category As String
        Get
            Return m_Category
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Category = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Category As String
    Public Property Number As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Number
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Number = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Number As Integer

    Public Sub New(category As String, number As Integer)
        Me.Category = category
        Me.Number = number
    End Sub End Class
```

It displays data initially like this:
[image]

But when I click my "change data" button data does not change?
What's the problem?

Comment: For one your ViewModel class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is what notifies the View that data has changed in the bound ViewModel.

Comment: @Nkosi: he's not changing any property of the view model, just the data in the `ObservableCollection<T>` object, which _does_ implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` as required.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are correct. I missed when OP created the new ViewModel in the event handler. That functionality should be moved to a command rather than the event handler in code behind but that is a whole other topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the wrong data:

```vb
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim test As New TestPageViewModel
    test.changeData()
End Sub
```

In your button's `Click` event handler, you create a new view model object and call the `changeData()` on it. But that's not the view model object the view is using, nor do you do anything to make it the view model object the view is using.

The best thing would be to just get the actual view model and change that one:

```vb
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Dim view As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim test As TestPageViewModel = CType(view.DataContext, TestPageViewModel)
    test.changeData()
End Sub
```

The above assumes that the `Button` sending the `Click` event has inherited the `MainWindow`'s data context.

Comment: is there any simple method to change data displayed in UI by event raised by user when you are implementing MVVM?

Comment: @PankajPotdar: it's a bit broad to try to explain in comments, but... The basis for nearly all MVVM implementations is `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand`. The former provides for UI updates with model data changes, while the latter provides for receiving user input. A user input can result in `ICommand.Execute()` being called, which in turn can change some value in the model, which in turn causes `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event being raised, which allows the UI to update itself based on the new value.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong as I am using observable collection I don't need inotifyproperty changed Right? Can you give an examplease of best way to update data on UI when user gives input?

Comment: @Pankaj: If you are using a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (which `ObservableCollection<T>` does), and the only thing you care about are changes _to the collection_ (i.e. the property values of the individual elements of the collection don't change), then yes...that's sufficient. I can't give an example of "best way" to update data; it depends a lot on what you mean. Updating data on the UI should always happen through binding of a view model property to a UI property, but how to accept user input and modify the view model property depends on the specific scenario.